# Schedule a java program at a specific time daily in AWS and store the returned values in Parse server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parse-server

I am building an android app, which needs to get data from AWS. I need to know how to schedule a java program in AWS EC2 daily and store the calculated values in the Parse server, so that it is accessed by the app.

Comment: you can use cron job or Scheduler Task

Comment: Is it a Lambda service in AWS?

Comment: https://vexxhost.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-jobs-for-automation-on-ubuntu-14-04/